# Change histogram bar colours greater than a certain value

Tags: r, histogram

So far, I've managed to change the colour a single bar in a histogram following the example [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-October/178206.html)

```
test <- rnorm(100);
h <- hist(test);
b <- cut(1, h$breaks);
clr <- rep("grey", length(h$counts));
clr[b] <- "red";
plot(h, col=clr);
```

I want to be able to change the colour of histogram bins that are above a certain x-axis value - e.g. that are above 1 in the distribution function in the example. Part of the reason why I am having trouble is that I don't exactly understand the factor that `cut()` returns.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fundamentally you want a logical selector on `test` not on the `cut`s.

Here's what your cut object looks like:

```
> bks <- cut(test,10)
```

The levels are of type character:

> levels(bks)
>        [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCNNA.png) "(-2.53,-2.01]"   "(-2.01,-1.5]"    "(-1.5,-0.978]"   "(-0.978,-0.459]"
>        [5] "(-0.459,0.0596]" "(0.0596,0.578]"  "(0.578,1.1]"     "(1.1,1.62]"
>        [9] "(1.62,2.13]"     "(2.13,2.65]"

The data is of type numeric:

```
> head(as.numeric(bks))
[1] 5 6 6 6 3 5
```

Here's a solution using ggplot2 rather than making the cuts and so forth by hand:

```
test <- rnorm(100)
dat <- data.frame( x=test, above=test>1 )
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x,data=dat,geom="histogram",fill=above)
```

[image: ggplot2 histo]

Comment: +1 That is a lovely graph!  Does this work for variable width bins as well? e.g. when using `hist(test, breaks=c(-3,-2,-1,0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3)`

Comment: @AssadEbrahim Thanks.  ggplot2 is purdy.  Should be able to make variable-width bins but you might need your own question to figure out how :-)

Comment: Fair enough :)  (purdy?)

Comment: @AssadEbrahim That's my word and I'm stickin' to it.

Comment: Funny how context makes all the difference.  Focused on the technical bits and not picking up your light tone, I thought purdy was a technical term I'd not heard before.  Re-reading it now, it all becomes *purdy* clear ;)  ("pretty" for those not familiar with U.S. casual idiom)

Comment: If you want to be more concise the test can be put into the ggplot2 code:  `qplot(x, data = dat, geom = "histogram", fill = test > 1)`

Answer (score 8):

Change your colour vector, `clr`, so that it shows red whenever the bar is greater than 1 and grey otherwise.

```
clr <- ifelse(h$breaks < 1, "grey", "red")[-length(h$breaks)]
```

Then plot as before.

Comment: If you have the time, it's worth learning ggplot and prefering gsk's answer over this.  The base `hist` function is a pain to make pretty.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction for hist though.

Comment: ggplot renders slowly, and has poor documentation (where are the options specific to geom="histogram" documented?)

Comment: @user1244215: The examples on the `?geom_histogram` page are pretty thorough.  But reading the ggplot2 book is the arguably best way to get the hang of the syntax.