# Add a box on a plot

Tags: r, histogram

I would like to highlight the bar at the right tail of the distribution of my data. 
Since it is too small I suppose that the best way to do this is by adding a box with red margins around the bar (at 25.0 level on the x axis). 
How it is possible to add such box on an histogram plot?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027448/change-histogram-bar-colours-greater-than-a-certain-value) might help. If this is not what you are wanting could you update your question with a some code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to color both the bars and their borders independently. But for that you need to know how many of those you have !

Here is a proposition, when what you want to do is to single out the first bar on the right to a certain value (here 1.96):

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100)
res.hist <- hist(x, plot=FALSE)

n_bars <- length(res.hist$mids)
left_lim <- res.hist$breaks[1:n_bars]
col_bars <- c("steelblue", "gold")[ diff(left_lim >= 1.96) + 1 ]
col_borders <- c(NA, "red")[ diff(left_lim >= 1.96) +1 ]

plot(res.hist, col=col_bars, border=col_borders)
```

[image: Histogram with colored bars]