# Colouring a histogram beyond a certain value

Tags: r

Firstly I know this question has come up before, namely: [Change histogram bar colours greater than a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027448/change-histogram-bar-colours-greater-than-a-certain-value)
but despite that thread, I'm running into a confusing issue.

So, I have some data, and within that data I know that the variable houses$PPSQM has 4 values greater than 3000. So what I was trying to do was plot a histogram of the data with all the bars below 3000 being red and the ones above 3000 being grey. I know from viewing the histogram that there are 2 bars that are above 3000(for the sake of clarity, there's 2 values at 4000 and 2 at 5000) here's the code I was using:

```
clr <- ifelse(houses$PPSQM>3000, "grey", "red")

hist(houses$PPSQM,ylim = c(0, 50) ,xlab="Cost per Sq. Meter",ylab='Frequency',col = clr)
```

But the problem I'm having is: If I say houses$PPSQM>3000, in the if-else statement, then it's colouring all the bars red... and if I say houses$PPSQM<3000, then it's colouring all the bars grey!?

Any suggestions as to how I'd fix this?

Comment: Hi Alanis, if you can make the example reproducible it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: It's difficult to answer without seeing your data, but I suspect the issue is that you have more colours in `clr` than there are bars in your histogram. Remember that a histogram is not a bar plot: the values are placed into bins, not counted separately. Try `h <- hist(houses$PPSQM)` then see if `length(clr)` is more than `length(h$counts)`.

Comment: You were right, `lenght(clr)` equals 12535... and `length(h$counts)` equals 11. It's been one of those days... have it fixed now... thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to colour by breaks in the histogram, not by values in the data. Try this:

```
h   <- hist(houses$PPSQM)
clr <- ifelse(h$breaks > 3000, "red", "grey")
hist(houses$PPSQM, ylim = c(0, 50), xlab = "Cost per Sq.Meter", 
     ylab = 'Frequency', col = clr)
```

You might need to play with the `breaks` parameter (see `?hist`) to get it looking how you want. You might also want to use `>= 3000`.

Comment: Thanks, your comment above sent me on the right track to fixing it... which was by using the `breaks` parameter. Thanks for your help